# Variable-width non-breaking space in Word 2016 (including a possible solution)

Tags: unicode, microsoft-word-2016, whitespace, linebreaks, space

I'm using Word 2016 to write articles that must keep certain words on the same line. Therefore, I work with a lot of non-breaking spaces. The articles eventually go to print (or PDF), meaning there must be absolutely no visual difference between a regular space and a non-breaking space. I sometimes also send them as Word documents to editors, so there has to be no difference between the spaces when the file is opened in Word, either.

Word 2013 [mostly](https://devwrench.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/word-2013-non-breaking-space-width-an-end-to-the-insanity) eliminated fixed-width non-breaking space, meaning that when you typed Ctrl+Shift+Space, you got exactly what I need: a variable-width non-breaking space, which behaved just like a regular space. That's logical: a space is a space, and a reader looking at a page has no reason to get a different visual result when it's a non-breaking space. It was different for purely historical reasons, but Word 2013 at least partly fixed that.

Word 2016 [reverted](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_windows8-mso_2016/nonbreakable-space-justification-in-word-2016/4fa1ad30-004c-454f-9775-a3beaa91c88b) to fixed-width non-breaking space, which is precisely what we are trying to avoid. This occurs not just when typing Ctrl+Shift+Space, but also when inserting any Unicode character of this family, including U+00A0, U+2009 and U+202F. These either don't work (the line breaks), or they are fixed-width. Similarly, U+2007 is too *wide* (also fixed-width).

So far, I found a single solution: typing U+FEFF, then regular space, then U+FEFF again. U+FEFF is "Zero Width No-Break Space", so it does not produce a space itself, but keeps on the same line what's before and after the regular space. Visually, this produces an identical result to a variable-width non-breaking space.

The problem is, first, it's cumbersome to type; and, second, when the file is edited in Word, you get a strange, interruptive feel - it's three characters instead of one, two of which are invisible, etc. If it was possible to merge this character sequence into a single keyboard shortcut, that would be helpful, but still wouldn't resolve the second problem.

I read the other threads online for the last few days; none helped (expectedly, many resort to the historical parables). So, what is a streamlined way to get a variable-width non-breaking space in Word 2016? Either a Unicode character I haven't yet discovered, a compatibility setting that would make Word 2016 behave like Word 2013 in this regard, or any other solution. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way than yours. However, you can combine typing U+FEFF, then regular space, then U+FEFF again and make it into a shortcut on your keyboard.

Add a macro in Word with the following code:  `Selection = ChrW(65279) & " " & ChrW(65279)`

ChrW adds a Unicode character, 65279 is the decimal code for U+FEFF.

Comment: My Word program (version 16.46 on macOS) complained about the parentheses around the number `65279` constituting invalid syntax.